# AngularJS : date format filter not formatting date

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to format date returned in API result set in format MM dd, yyyy but for some reason it is not working. Below is the code I am using, Can someone please tell me what I am missing / doing wrong here? and how to achieve the above required format

```
          <div>
            <div>
              <p>Date Added:</p>
              {{memberData.DateJoined | date: 'MM dd, YYYY'}}
            </div>
          </div>
```

also tried it using

```
          <div>
            <div>
              <p>Date Added:</p>
              {{memberData.DateJoined | date: 'MM dd, yyyy'}}
            </div>
          </div>
```

Date returned by API is in format:

```
     DatePosted: "2014-05-15 00:00:00"
```

Not working definition:
Date displayed as 2014-05-15 00:00:00 while it should be displayed as 05 15, 2014 OR May 15, 2014

Comment: Please define "not working". What do you get instead of the expected result?

Comment: And what is the type and value of `memberData.DateJoined`?

Comment: @JBNizet Question updated with memberData.DateJoined content, thanks

Comment: Read the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date. It explains what input the date filter accepts. Your input is not one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it's just a typo, but `YYYY` should be lowercase:

```
{{memberData.DateJoined | date: 'MM dd, yyyy'}}
```

**Edit:** Your source format `2014-05-15 00:00:00` is not a valid source for Angular, so you need to convert it to a `Date` object first in the controller:

```
$scope.DateJoined = new Date('2014-05-15 00:00:00');
```

And then you can use:

```
{{ DateJoined | date: 'MM dd, yyyy'}}
```

See example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeqLH/).

Comment: Tried it using yyyy and YYYY both didn't work. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. On the angular site i read : `Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats` so it should work also with a string like `2014-05-15 00:00:00`

Answer (score 3):

In your angular controller create a new function to fix the date returned:

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope){

$scope.fixDate = function(date){
    return new Date(date);
};

..... rest of your controller goes here.
});
```

In the HTML:

```
{{fixDate(DatePosted) | date:  "MM dd, yyyy"}}
```

You can also use this function if you are returning an array of dates for example "orders_date"  from database, it can be used with `ng-repeat` directive

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your date string into a `Date` object:

```
DatePosted = new Date(DatePosted)
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details?

Comment: Your date is in a string format, which angular's date filter don't seem to know how to handle. If you replace that string with a `Date` object (which can get a string in its constructor), the filter will do as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/5xG2M/

Comment: Sorry but jsfiddle returns an error when trying to run your code. Can you please check it?

Comment: weird, works in Chrome but not in FF. Your date format is really strange. Try http://jsfiddle.net/5xG2M/1/

Comment: Please review selected answer. This is the correct answer